# VW EOS ESC Error message

Tags: engine, electrical, battery, tires, vw

My VW 2015 EOS works great but since my last tire rotation, the ESC Stabilization Control Error appears while drive on dry roads at a constant speed.  Engine slows, cannot accelerate.  Must pull off the road, shut off the engine and restart. Everything works well for many trips, then it happens again.  What is causing this error message?

After first incident, someone suggested my battery was bad, so replaced the battery.  But problem persists.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the car checked for codes?

Comment: No, haven't checked codes.  Someone suggested to replace the ABS wheel sensors.

Comment: It's hardly ever a good idea to change sensors without a diagnosis. Most of the time the costs are really high. Getting the codes read can point to things like speed sensor faults or wheel size variations etc. If a light is on there are codes stored. Once you get them post them here for more help.

Comment: Hooked up a scanner and found one code.  "Communication problem with transmission control module."  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

I appears the cause of the transmissions lock-up into neutral was caused by the HUM device purchased through Verizon which is inserted into the OBDI port to monitor engine function.  Since removing the HUM from the vehicle, I have had NO transmission lock-ups in several months.  I recommend NOT using the HUM by Verizon at the risk of a potentially lethal vehicle crash.